# Ajax function not working readystate 1

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I'm currently working on jquery and I want to get the info from an API call using ajax, I'm doing this on a blur function that gets the value from an input and then calls the end point, but the ajax call stays on readystate 1, I don't know exactly why.

This is how I'm doing it.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("change","#calc_shipping_method",function(){
            $('.rp_calc_shipping').trigger('click');
        });

    $('.shipping_postcode input,.shipping_state input').blur(function () {
                $(".loaderimage").show();
                element=$(this);
                var datastring = $(this).closest(".woocommerce-shipping-calculator").serialize();
                if($("input.variation_id").length>0){
                    datastring=datastring+"&variation_id="+$("input.variation_id").val();
                }
                if($("input[name=quantity]").length>0){
                    datastring=datastring+"&current_qty="+$("input[name=quantity]").val();
                }

                var zip = $("#calc_shipping_postcode").val();
                // THIS DOENS'T WORK
                var state = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    crossOrigin: true,
                    url: "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/"+zip,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {

                        alert ("hello world");

                    }
                });
                state = state['responseJSON']['estado'];
                //03134-001

                datastring.replace("calc_shipping_state=","calc_shipping_state="+state);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: rp_ajax_url+"?action=update_shipping_method",
                    data: datastring,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(".loaderimage").hide();
                        element.parent().parent().find('.shippingmethod_container').html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
  });})(jQuery);
```

The thing is that the alert on the ajax works but the readystate of the object is 1.

Comment: Typically the processing of the result data is performed in the success method.  `state = state['responseJSON']['estado'];`  looks to be expecting the ajax to operate in a synchronous manner, which ajax does not by default.

Comment: Right, so, the readystate is 1. that sounds correct. `state = state['responseJSON']['estado'];` should fail because the json hasn't been received yet.

Comment: i put async: false and worked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved adding `async: false`,

like this:

```
        var state = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossOrigin: true,
            url: "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/"+zip,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false
        });
```